# How to achieve Sampling in Java?

Tags: java, image-processing, sampling

I am trying to convert a 8-bit image to 4-bit image using sampling ,but not sure how to do it .
Any code samples would be really helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show the code you tried and explain what problems you encountered.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use JAI (java advanced imaging). You can download this from oracle (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/current-142188.html). There are tons of documentation available.

Comment: What if the link won't be valid some day?

Comment: yes that will do . Thanks

Comment: @Maroun: I'm sure that the search "jai java download" would end in some useful links. What is a better way to provide this advice?

Comment: @chris well, the question is off topic since it's asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library. I think that the best thing to do in the future is mention that as a comment and vote to close the question (when you'll have privileges).

Comment: @Maroun: i just wanted to give him an idea about how to get any further. Next time i will write a comment - thx for your assistance.